# Can't import module with bsub

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have to run a Python script with bsub but it doesn't work because the script cannot import a module (Scipy).

When I run the script locally under Python, it works perfectly. But when I use bsub, it cannot find Scipy... I put the path of the module in my `PYTHONPATH`, but it doesn't change anything.

I checked if my `.bashrc` was good in the cluster and it's ok, I can also run my script directly in Python with ssh, but not with bsub. Any ideas?

Comment: Use bsub to start an interactive job, and see if you can run the script.  It sounds like when jobs are submitted, the environment they start in is different than what you get when you ssh into a worker in the cluster (this is with PlatformLSF, right?).

Comment: LSF, yes.
I will try this, thanks.

Comment: I tried this : bsub -I python2 test.py
But it doesn't worked...

If that true that bsub start jobs in different environment, which seems because otherwise I can't understand what append, How can I load my .bashrc in bsub?

Comment: Do you think it's possible to set a PYTHONPATH for bsub with the "setenv" variable ? I don't know bsub too much.

Comment: You could even do something like `import sys; sys.path.append("/foo/bar")` but I would concentrate my efforts on debugging the bsub enviroment

Comment: You're going to want to start an interactive shell thru bsub, not run the script.

Comment: Finally I just add import sys; sys.path.append(".../Python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages") as said Giupo because it's what I had in mind too and it worked. So I will leave it like this because I have no time to waste with this at the moment...
Thanks everybody for your help!